# Finding the global maximum value

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find the global maximum value for $f(x)=12\sin x + 5\cos x$ in $[0, 2\pi]$ 
I started solving the question by: $f'(x)=12\cos x - 5\sin x = 0$
And $\dots\tan x = \frac{12}{5}$ how can I solve for $x?$ 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the $\arctan$ function to calculate $x$.

Then you can use also the "Compositions of trig and inverse trig functions":

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities

Comment: It isn't clear for me

Comment: the critical points are $$x_1=arctan(12/5)$$ and $$x_2=\pi+arctan(12/5)$$ as the function is continuos, limited and periodic the critical points are extrema points for the function

Comment: @gimusi answer the question on white paper please